# Mosfets get Very hot at relatively low power drop(As E load)

Tags: mosfet, heat

I'm trying to build my own E load according to the circuit I made here:

[image]

Now not having a thermal lab and very good understanding at how it suppose to work with the thermodynamics but when I set the output load to 10V 2A 20W the 2 beefy mosfets I've connected in parallel(only 2 mosfets and not 4 like in the schematic) the E load block gets very hot to the touch to a point where it is it's limit and they are connected to quite a big heat sink.

Mosfet used:

IXFH75N10 TO-247

And the question it:
Is that normal?

I came across a few E loads on aliexpress which seem to have around 5 time's the performance (Mosfet amount and heat sink size counted) like those:

[E load 75W no heat sink](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32680278775.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.34.39b549a90nysgq&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.14976.157518.0&scm_id=1007.14976.157518.0&scm-url=1007.14976.157518.0&pvid=77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.14976.157518.0,pvid:77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2358_668%23808%234093%23748_668%23888%233325%2320_4976%230%23157518%230_4976%232711%237538%231_4976%233223%2310815%235_4976%233104%239652%231_4976%233141%239887%236_668%232846%238113%23609_668%232717%237567%23912_)

[E load 250W](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32983503840.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.46.39b549a90nysgq&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.14976.157518.0&scm_id=1007.14976.157518.0&scm-url=1007.14976.157518.0&pvid=77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.14976.157518.0,pvid:77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2358_668%23808%234093%23748_668%23888%233325%2320_4976%230%23157518%230_4976%232711%237538%231_4976%233223%2310815%235_4976%233104%239652%231_4976%233141%239887%236_668%232846%238113%23609_668%232717%237567%23912_)

[ELoad 60W with heatsink](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32471791125.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.8.39b549a90nysgq&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.14976.157518.0&scm_id=1007.14976.157518.0&scm-url=1007.14976.157518.0&pvid=77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.14976.157518.0,pvid:77394485-d9fd-4023-b236-0645ebb4a4d1,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2358_668%23808%234093%23748_668%23888%233325%2320_4976%230%23157518%230_4976%232711%237538%231_4976%233223%2310815%235_4976%233104%239652%231_4976%233141%239887%236_668%232846%238113%23609_668%232717%237567%23912_)

Can't understand why.

Comment: You haven't told us the heatsink specification (temperature rise in K/W) and the temperature rise. Did you do any thermal calculations?

Comment: 20W dissipated in 2 MOSFETs is 10W per mosfet. What package are they in, and what heatsink are they on? Show us your thermal calculations.

Comment: So the mosfets are IXFH75N10 TO-247 Not sure about the exact heat sink specs are sins it's recycled and modified but it's "decent" at size of 30*50*115mm with fins out of aluminum.

Comment: "decent" .... the device has an Rjc of 0.42 unless we are talking about a 50cm x 50cm heatsink, you probably have something that is at best ... 10C/W thus the total thermal impedance, junction-ambientis going to be 10-12 C/W . You are dissipating 10W => thus the junction is going to be ~ 100C above ambient -> 125C, the case will feel HOT!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else is wrong, but  you're missing a connection on the gates of Q3/Q4. Decent chance it won't be stable. Check that with an oscilloscope.

I would estimate your 30 * 50 * 115mm heatsink to have \$R_{\theta}\$ of perhaps 3.5 or 4°C/W so 20W would result in a heatsink temperature of 95°C to 105°C at a 25°C ambient.

The transistor cases, and the junctions will be even hotter, of course. The "75W" Aliexpress load definitely expects the user to add a heat sink **and** a fan. With a powerful fan you can get a much lower \$R_{\theta}\$ compared to natural convection.

Comment: Well the Q3/Q4 are not connected right now as I mentioned so you say with the currect transistor setup it is normal that the whole block gets so hot?

Comment: The heat sink temperature rise, as estimated above, is essentially independent of the number of transistors contributing to it.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong but to make that design efficient I should be choosing the cheapest mosfet(sins performance doesn't matter and they go to heat conversion anyways...) and get the biggest ones out there?

Comment: Also seems between the two FETS in the bank just heat up evenly one much hotter than the other.. Could the way they are driven be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

**All** active power loads need a heatsink as the transistor has a high thermal resistance.

Your first item specifies Mica, Thermal grease and a fan is essential.

All packages have a low thermal resistance to the case and high to ambient meaning the case gets hot without a heatsink.

TO-247
Maximum Junction-to-Ambient Rth(JA) 62 °C/W
Maximum Junction-to-Case (drain) Rth(JC) 0.5  °C/W

The current sensor R can be 50 mV at max I and then use gain on the Op Amp to increase output or easier, just scale down the voltage with a R divider.

e.g. 50mV/2A = 25mOhm. Otherwise, you need a 1W R @ 0.1 Ohms

Only use up to 50% of the max rated temp rise for safety margin i.e. 50'C which will still burn.

To dissipate 75W a forced air of 5m/s over the fins will reduce any heatsink Rth(CA) significantly such as a CPU sink & fan.

I might use some old CPU heatsink & fan fastened with power FET, mica, grease and torque spec to make an inexpensive active load. Use a  control voltage or pot above the threshold voltage Vgs(th) to > 2x Vgs(th) to obtain a reasonable max load usually up to 15V.

Comment: OK just seem that It's going to  be quite a challenge getting 200W E load with this setup, also does it matter how you drive the mosfet in this config? I've seen people using quad opamp with seperate shunt resistors to drive the E load mosfet for some unclear reasons...